# Nested loop does not convert strings to datetime.date object or quits midway

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy

I have a list of dictionaries called measures where each dictionary contains a date key with a date value in string format:

measures=

```
[{'date': '2010-01-01', 'prcp': 0.15142857142857144, 'tobs': 
69.71428571428571}, {'date': '2010-01-02', 'prcp': 0.002857142857142857, 
'tobs': 67.0}, {'date': '2010-01-03', 'prcp': 0.0, 'tobs': 74.0}, {'date': 
'2010-01-04', 'prcp': 0.0014285714285714286, 'tobs': 75.0}, {'date': '2010- 
01-05', 'prcp': 0.005, 'tobs': 74.5}]
```

I would like to convert the date strings to datetime.date objects specifically as I need the exact format for sqlalchemy. I do not want a datetime.datetime format and I am positive the current format is string format. When I use the following nested loop:

```
for record in measures:
    for key, val in record.items():
        record['date']=datetime.strptime(record['date'],'%Y-%m-%d').date()
        print(type(record['date']))
```

I get the error: TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date
but commenting out the conversion code and checking to see type of each date record after running the conversion, I see that 4 records get converted to datetime.date but quits after that:

```
for record in measures:
    for key, val in record.items():
        ##record['date']=datetime.strptime(record['date'],'%Y-%m-%d').date()
        print(type(record['date']))

Output:
<class 'datetime.date'>
<class 'datetime.date'>
<class 'datetime.date'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

Any idea how I can fix this? I have 20000 items in the original dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be this:

```
for record in measures:
    record['date']=datetime.strptime(record['date'],'%Y-%m-%d').date()
    print(type(record['date']))
```

Comment: Obviously, repeated *key-value* iterations on a previously converted date value will raise an error. +1

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could also use `dateutil.parser`

```
from dateutil import parser
for item in measures:
    item['date'] = parser.parse(item['date']).date( )

[{'date': datetime.date(2010, 1, 1),
  'prcp': 0.15142857142857144,
  'tobs': 69.71428571428571},
 {'date': datetime.date(2010, 1, 2),
  'prcp': 0.002857142857142857,
  'tobs': 67.0},
 {'date': datetime.date(2010, 1, 3), 
  'prcp': 0.0, 
  'tobs': 74.0},
 {'date': datetime.date(2010, 1, 4),
  'prcp': 0.0014285714285714286,
  'tobs': 75.0},
 {'date': datetime.date(2010, 1, 5), 
  'prcp': 0.005, 
  'tobs': 74.5}]
```